# Using a xml file to store data from a database and select these data for exibition would decrease the bandwidth consumption?

Tags: php, mysql, xml

I have this website(php) with a mysql database, but almost all the pages will select about 500 rows from the database, so I was wondering if would be smart, safe and "ok" to use a XML file that would store the data from database so the user could use less from his internet band, since the website wouldn't open a mysql connection all the time like before

- Now 1)site get data from database
- What I want to do 1)XML monthly get data from database and store it. 2)When the user access the site he will load data from the XML file

Thank you.

Comment: Why do you think that selecting 500 rows from a database would be any less efficient in terms f bandwidth than returning an xml file of 500 "rows"? It's the same volume of data. Is there any particular reason why you'r selecting 500 rows? Could you select less?

Comment: That is exactly my question, I wonder if data from a XML file (since it is local) would spend less band, do you think it is "the same thing" ? The rows wll be "customizable", you click "country" it return countries, when click city return cities

Comment: How would the xml file be local if you generate it on the server side?

Comment: No, I mean "local" cause it wouldn't use a mysql connection, since it is a file I wonder if it would work just like a php, html, js file instead force a connection all the time

Comment: You're simply replacing a database with an XML file; you still need to do searching and etc if you want countries and cities through a medium that isn't designed with efficient searching in mind, compared to a database which should be designed/configured for searching.... yes, you can replace it, but not more efficiently... xpath isn't as efficient as SQL, and you don't have any indexes on the data in xml to optimise searching, whereas a database should be indexed

Comment: You might consider caching the results of complex data queries against  database where the data rarely changes; but simply replacing a database with an xml file  isn't going to provide any real benefits, nd is much more likely to be slow and less efficient, and add extra complexity to your code to handle searches

Comment: I had not think about it, I really forget about the "search thing", and what if I want to do that with mysql count? Now I have 15 different numbers to show to user, these numbers will change about each 6 months, would be smart to use the XML like a "mirror" for the database? So instead of call 15 "select count from table" (different tables) I could have this 15 numbers in XML file and create a admin page to update the numbers from database to XML, still useless?

Comment: this is called premature optimization (one that will actually slow things down)

Comment: This is new for me, any way to get around this "problem" or should I just accept the mysql calls ?

Comment: What is your issue with calling a database to execute a query? It's how millions of sites around the world store their data without problem.... and if you have all these select counts that never change, then store the results in a results table and just query that, perhaps using a cron job to execte the counts and update the results table periodically; that way, you have a single query

Comment: I don't know, I just guess if user would spend less bandwidth, but your ideas really seems to be smarter, I going to create this ResultTable with the schedule, more way easier, and solves the problem of +/- 4 pages on my website that need just the "counts", really thank you guys!

Comment: Why do you think the database connection will add to the user's bandwidth? Do you make the database connection from user's web-browser or client? Usually the db connection is done from a webserver and only the results go over the wire to the user (which should be the same for db or xml or else it's not what you want)